# 'list index out of range' after .pop()

Tags: python

I want to iterate on a list and remove an element if it meets some conditions.
But if I remove the element with .pop the list becomes shorter and I get the error : `IndexError: list index out of range`.

```
mylist = ["a","a","b","c","d","e"]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    while mylist[i] == "a":
        mylist.pop(i)
        
print(mylist)
```

Is it possible to decrease of 1 the range of the for loop whenever I remove an element from a list?
How can I solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Something like this, `[item for item in mylist if item != 'a']`